Help converting counta to an array formula
I need help adding turning my formula into an Array Formula
I am using the COUNTA to count all cells in row range that are not empty ignoring blank cells with formulas. It works, but will not copy down the entire count total column.
=(COUNTA(C8:AU8))


To return a COUNTA for C:AU in rows 8 to the end of the sheet:
=BYROW(C8:AU, LAMBDA(row, COUNTA(row)))

To skip empty rows:
=BYROW(C8:AU, LAMBDA(row, IFERROR(1/(1/COUNTA(row)))))

BYROW  COUNTA  IFERROR  LAMBDA
